# ACL not working on btrfs filesystem

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-14.04, acl, btrfs

I'm trying to use ACL's to make all new files and folder in a directory belong to a certain group, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I've run these commands in the directory:

```
setfacl -d -m group:"groupname":rwx .
setfacl -m group:"groupname":rwx .
```

New files and folders still belong to the group of the user who created them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ACLs work fine. But you're expecting them to do things which they never did at all.

Specifically, ACLs never *change* file ownership. Instead they add *additional* access entries – that is, in addition to the "main" group, there is now a *second* group that also has +rwx access.

For many purposes, that should actually be enough. But if you need the "main" group to be changed, you'll need a different feature – on Linux, the "setgid" flag on directories has that effect:

```
chmod g+s .
```

*(Note that there's no equivalent for the owner itself; `u+s` has no effect on directories.*)

Comment: Huh, thanks. I could have sworn it didn't work, but now it does. It's just not visible in the same way, just like you said. Thanks!

Comment: You might have had the 'mask' deny access; in POSIX ACLs, if there is an ACL and someone does `chmod g-rwx` it doesn't change the main group's access, it changes the access for all ACL entries as well.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`btrfs` has `acl` support enabled as a default `mount` option.

However inside an `lxc` container on a `btrfs` filesystem setting a sticky `gid` with `chmod g+s` does not work (it works just fine inside a container on an `ext` filesystem) - it needs to be set by the `lxc` host.